# Load balanced CMs, temporary upload location and sticky sessions

Tags: web8, cme, content-manager

The [online docs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-6E899840-8936-49A9-B100-CD8B9FF0CDF4&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-D7D99E82-39E1-45B9-B90A-FB263A45D0F5.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-6E899840-8936-49A9-B100-CD8B9FF0CDF4&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DbinaryContentStorage&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1525092955022&currentQuery=binaryContentStorage&currentScope=) recommend using a network folder that all CM instances must have write access to, in an outscaled scenario.

The path to which is added to the `temporaryFolder` attribute of the `binaryContentStorage` element in Tridion.ContentManager.config.

Is this still needed if you're utilising stick sessions (again, as the [online docs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A1942C6C-34BB-46F2-A075-FD145FF6101C&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-D7D99E82-39E1-45B9-B90A-FB263A45D0F5.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A1942C6C-34BB-46F2-A075-FD145FF6101C&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DbinaryContentStorage&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1525092955022&currentQuery=binaryContentStorage&currentScope=) suggest you should for load-balanced CMEs)?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both settings are required. The reason is that the sticky sessions are enabled per WCF client. In order to create a multimedia component (or TBB), two WCF clients are used: one for uploading a binary and another one for creating an item in TCM. These two clients may "stick" to different CM instances; hence you need to ensure the path to uploaded binary will be accessible from any instance.